# Consulta CASE SQL para SAP

Tags: sql, sap

Quería consultar sobre un tema que no pude llevar adelante. Estoy iniciando la carga de consulta mediante SQL para SAP, y no puedo realizar un CASE donde pida el número de empleado, y según el numero de empleado me cargue el nombre del vendedor que corresponde para ese número de vendedor.

Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier aporte para poder solucionar esta duda.

Dejo la sintaxis aquí

```
SELECT T0."CardName", 
       T0."LicTradNum",
       T0."GroupNum", 
       T1."GroupNum",
       T2."InstNum",
       T2."PaymntsNum", 
       T2."VolumDscnt", 
       T1."Comments",
       T3."OwnerCode", 
       T1."CntrlBnk",
       T1."SlpCode",
       T1."PeyMethod" 
       CASE t1."SlpCode"
          WHEN -1 THEN 'VENDEDOR 1 '
          WHEN 2 THEN 'VENDEDOR 1 '
          WHEN 3 THEN 'VENDEDOR 1 '
          WHEN 7 THEN 'VENDEDOR 1 '
        END
FROM OCRD T0  
INNER JOIN OQUT T1 ON T0."CardCode" = T1."CardCode" 
INNER JOIN OCTG T2 ON T0."GroupNum" = T2."GroupNum" 
INNER JOIN OINV T3 ON T1."CardName" = T3."CardName" 
WHERE T1."GroupNum" = 7
```

Comment: Me parece que le falta el `ELSE 'otro vendedor' END` al `6CASE` además, todos los `THEN` está retornando "VENDEDOR 1", ¿esto es correcto?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que es lo que le pasa a esta consulta? recibis algun error?

Comment: la coma que le falta al query es un error de escritura de aca o realmente le falta? (y ese podria ser el error?)

Comment: Desde ya muchas gracias, y paso a responder, ya agregue el ELSE y END pero el error que recibo es en la linea del CASE.

Comment: La coma que falta donde la estarias viendo ? Y la consulta esta completa asi, y funciona sin el CASE que incorpore, es para un LAYOUT de SAP B1.

Comment: Claro, funciona sin el case, porque falta una coma entre T1."PeyMethod" y el case ;)

Comment: No es mas que un error de sintaxis. La declaración de un CASE dentro de un SELECT es valida de esta manera:

CASE ProductLine  
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'  
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'  
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'  
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'   
END 

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/969f0434-15ef-43de-9ba9-7510974a6145/case-dentro-de-select?forum=sqlserveres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la correción, agregue la coma (,) luego del ultimo campo de la tabla, y realice el THEN para cada caso que corresponde del SlpCode:

```
SELECT T0."CardName", T0."LicTradNum",T0."GroupNum", T1."GroupNum",T2."InstNum",T2."PaymntsNum", T2."VolumDscnt", T1."Comments",T3."OwnerCode", T1."CntrlBnk",T1."SlpCode",T1."PeyMethod",
CASE t1."SlpCode"
WHEN  -1 THEN 'VENDEDOR 1 '
WHEN  2 THEN 'VENDEDOR 2  '
WHEN  3 THEN 'VENDEDOR 3  '
WHEN 7 THEN 'VENDEDOR 3  '
ELSE 'otro vendedor' 
END
FROM OCRD T0  INNER JOIN OQUT T1 ON T0."CardCode" = T1."CardCode" INNER JOIN OCTG T2 ON T0."GroupNum" = T2."GroupNum" INNER JOIN OINV T3 ON T1."CardName" = T3."CardName" 
WHERE T1."GroupNum" = 7
```

Comment: En los casos donde el error es simplemente un error tipografico, no deben contestarse las preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

No es mas que un error de sintaxis. La declaración de un CASE dentro de un SELECT es valida de esta manera:

CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
END

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/969f0434-15ef-43de-9ba9-7510974a6145/case-dentro-de-select?forum=sqlserveres

Comment: En los casos en que las preguntas solo sean por errores tipograficos, no deben contestarse...